# Implementation of an 'install' target with SCons

Tags: scons

I try to setup a build system to build a shared lib *MySharedLib* and a binary *MyBinary* that rely on *MySharedLib*. The build system should be able to install *MySharedLib* and *MyBinary* when asked for it, and only when asked for it.

```
import os.path

env = Environment()
env.Append(CCFLAGS='-g -Wall -ansi -O2')

prefix = '/usr/local'
lib_dir = os.path.join(prefix, 'lib')
bin_dir = os.path.join(prefix, 'bin')
Export('env prefix lib_dir bin_dir')

libMySharedLib = SConscript('libMySharedLib/SConscript')
MyBinary   = SConscript('MyBinary/SConscript')

env.Alias('install', env.Install(lib_dir, libMySharedLib))
env.Alias('install', env.Install(bin_dir, MyBinary))
```

When I run SCons with no command line arguments, MySharedLib and MyBinary are built, but it also it try to install them. I want them installed only just when I ask for the *install* target. I tried many times, read the docs, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Interestingly, I have the exact opposite problem (like described in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189440/scons-always-install-after-build)) I want install to happen with build, but I can't force it to work! I have to explicitly say `scons install` or `scons /usr/local/bin` (for your directory example). When you saw this, did you run scons in /usr/local? The difference is also that you do Install with result of a SConscript, while I do it with result of some Builder, but why would that matter...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, and when no target are set into the scons script, scons builds every target in '.'. You can control which targets to build by default with the Default function:

```
lib = SConscript('libMySharedLib/SConscript')
bin = SConscript('MyBinary/SConscript')

env.Alias('install', env.Install(lib_dir, lib))
env.Alias('install', env.Install(bin_dir, bin))

# By default (scons called with no explicit target), only build bin
Default(bin)
```

AFAIK, there is no way to tell scons to build nothing, although you could create a dummy target I suppose.

Comment: You can call Default(None) to specify no targets by default. About half way down the page: http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x2805.html#AEN2824