# scons - always install after build

Tags: scons

I want scons to always install the built file in several additional directories.

I created the usual install builder with alias a shown in user manual and it installs correctly when I use `scons install` but I prefer it to run automatically after the target is built and I cannot figure out how to specify the dependencies.

```
Target = Program(...)
Env.Alias('install', Env.Install(FinalDir, Target))
```

Should the target depend on install or vice versa or should I use something else?

Comment: Can you show us your Install() builder scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went the wrong way of defining `install` target and trying to figure out how to run it automatically.

I solved it by aliasing the Install builder to the real file names I wanted to install instead of `install`.

```
Env.Alias('/some/dir/filename', Env.Install('/some/dir', Target))
```

Comment: Somehow does not work for me. If I alias "install" to some top destination install directory, then "scons install" would trigger install (and build) all through the build tree. But without "install" alias `env.Install(location, result)` just doesn't do a thing. And aliasing a particular destination name also doesn't do anything. I thought Install() builder is essentially a file copy with path creation and maybe some registering among the installed items, which is what I really want.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine.  I suspect what you're really asking is you want it to *always* install the target in FinalDir even if you don't specify 'install' as a command-line arg, i.e. when you just say `scons`.  In that case, check out the `Default()` method in the [man page](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html). You can add your 'install' alias to the set of default targets SCons builds.  (The "default default" if you don't change it and don't pass any targets on the command line is everything under the current dir.)

Comment: env.Default(targets) specifies a list of default targets, which will be built by scons if no explicit targets are given on the command line. What I'm looking for is a way to add 'install' target to a list of targets given on the command line.

Comment: Your users may not like it if you do this, especially if they're cleaning (with scons -c) or building something unrelated.  However, if you want to do it, I think adding your node to BUILD_TARGETS (see the man page) ought to work. (Haven't tested it though.)